# Lock Django DB on 10 concurrent uwsgi workers - how to?

Tags: django, concurrency, sqlite, locking

What is the most elegant way to

**lock the Django DB** while I make a **complex transaction** (read, decide, write)

... during which no other uwsgi worker should have access (or at least no *write* access) to that table?

I am using Django + db.sqlite3 + uwsgi (+ nginx).

Thanks a lot!

---

EDIT 1:

Fantastic, of course Django itself solves the problem. Much easier than I had expected. Good that I asked around!

Here is my yellow-marker highlighted version http://marker.to/W0CbtZ
of the manual page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/transactions/ about transactions.

Thanks, IRC :-)

---

EDIT 2:

I am actually looking for a **database LOCK** for which all processes wait until it's their turn.

What I learnt today, I implemented now:

```
try: 
   with transaction.atomic():
      foo(obj)
      obj.save()     # (*)
except IntegrityError:
   print "debug information"
```

So I won't get an inconsistent DB ever. But now (*) is throwing an exception "OperationalError: database is locked" (and [this suggestion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#database-is-locked-errors) is not helping, too). Which I understand, because dozens of such transactions are trying to save-to-DB at the same time.

What I rather need is something like

```
lock = threading.Lock()
...
with lock:
    foo(obj)
    obj.save()
```

But not *threading*, because it needs to lock across all uwsgi worker *processes*.

Any idea welcome. What is the most elegant way to do this? Which part of the manual to look into now? I googled already, and didn't find answers - that's why I ask here.

Thanks a lot.

---

EDIT 3:

As I still had a small percentage of  "OperationalError: database is locked" failures (even with [my threading.Lock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28035529)), I implemented @knbk's suggestion - but it didn't work, this is the output:

```
up to here all is fine
ALERT! cannot start a transaction within a transaction
Out[]: False
```

This is how I implemented it, following @knbk's [code example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28034823):

```
from django.db import connection

def foobar():
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('BEGIN IMMEDIATE')  # also tried 'BEGIN EXCLUSIVE'
    try:
        myObjects = myModel.objects.filter(myFilter="myfilter")
        if myCondition(myObjects) > 0:
            obj = myObjects[0]
            print "up to here all is fine"
            obj.save()                                          
    except Exception as e:
        connection.rollback()
        print "ALERT!", e
        return False
    finally:
        connection.commit()
    return True
```

So ... what now?

---

EDIT 4:

I **solved it myself** now. I wrote a whole **lockbydir.DLock** class which uses directory existence and age - for locking across processes! Now I can simply lock access to the Django DB, and regardless which DB is used. Very happy. Perhaps you want to have a look? Here is the GIT:

https://github.com/drandreaskrueger/lockbydir

See the README. There are even 3 GIT-Players to watch the code examples execute live in your browser! Great, isn't it? ;-)

Thanks for your time, and attention!

Comment: Got this hint on IRC, will start reading it now: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/transactions/

Comment: Now (with postgresql) I get more double entries in my DB again, from with concurrent processes - so I am still missing a DB lock. Any help appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The right statements to acquire a lock are `BEGIN IMMEDIATE` and `BEGIN EXCLUSIVE`. The first will acquire a lock that prevents other processes from getting a write lock. The second will acquire a lock that also prevents other processes from getting a read lock.

Django does not provide a high-level api to execute these statements. Instead, you'll have to use a database cursor to execute these statements directly:

```
from django.db import connection

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('BEGIN IMMEDIATE')
try:
    my_objs = Model.objects.filter(...)
    etc...
except:
    connection.rollback()
finally:
    connection.commit()
```

**DISCLAIMER**: Note that this method, especially `COMMIT EXCLUSIVE`, will acquire a lock on the complete database. Sqlite doesn't support row or table level locking. No other process will be able to write to any part of the database during the lock, and with an exclusive lock they won't even be able to read. If this is a frequent operation or you have a write-heavy database, consider using MySQL or PostgreSQL, which both support row/table level locking. That might be a good idea anyway if your site requires 10 concurrent workers.

Comment: will the next read request to a locked database/table/row wait? i.e. a standard `ObjectModel.objects.all()` call in another request?

Comment: @warath-coder Yes, until the database times out. The default is to wait 5 seconds before raising an error. @akrueger I tested it, and you don't need to turn off autocommit. Furthermore, you can use the `connection.commit()` and `connection.rollback()` methods to commit/rollback the transaction. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. I tried it. See my Edit 3 above.

Comment: @akrueger What's the actual operation you need the lock for? If it is very expensive (i.e. takes more than 5 seconds), other connections will time out. You can [increase the timeout](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/databases/#database-is-locked-errors) or change to a database that allows for more concurrency. Note that your `threading.Lock` only prevents other threads in the same process from doing the exact same operation, not from doing other operations which read/write from/to the database.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Yes, I know about threading.Lock() and its limits. And with concurrent uwsgi workers, I somehow still hope for a django.db.Lock() solution.

Comment: What is the actual operation?  I read some of my objects, then depending on what I find there, I save an instance of the same model of objects. See my "Edit 3" above. During this (even though short, 2-3ms) complex transaction, no other thread/process should try to do the same. That's why I want a DB lock. I have increased the timeout to 30, but the  "OperationalError: database is locked" happens immediately, in much less than 5 seconds.

Comment: I actually found many bug reports about similiar problems; it seems to be a well known (but not easy to replicate) problem with sqlite, and for many years now. Let's hope that is the case, and when I get rid of sqlite, this goes away. Finally looking into postgresql now.

Comment: Now testing with postgresql. First on Windows, for my development system (production system will be on Linux).  Postgresql 9.4 with psycopg2-2.5.4. Just got it running, migrated the DB, all working again. But a huge, immense, exorbitant DISAPPOINTMENT: My app is much much MUCH slower with postgresql than it was ever with sqlite.  Meh. Next: Testing on Linux if the same slowness.

Comment: On Linux it is not as bad. For repeated calls of the same thing, sqlite is still more than 10 times faster (it seems to cache the last result in RAM?), but for non-repeated calls, postgresql is only ~30% slower. I can live with that.

Comment: BUT now (with pg) I get more double entries in my DB again with concurrent processes - so I am still missing a DB lock. Any help appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: @akrueger Yes, locking in PostgreSQL [works differently](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html). If you want to know more about that you should probably ask another question. PostgreSQL can be very fast with proper optimization (indexes, settings etc.), and I can guarantee that the difference will disappear when your application gets a decent amount of workload. Database optimization is a huge topic, so you can't expect to get everything out of it right away. Careful profiling of expensive queries and then optimizing them one by one will get you the best results.

Comment: Thanks @knbk. I **solved it myself** now. I wrote a whole **lockbydir.DLock** class which uses directory existence and age - for locking across processes! Now I can simply lock access to the Django DB, and regardless which DB is used. Very happy. Perhaps you want to have a look? Here is the GIT:

https://github.com/drandreaskrueger/lockbydir

See the README. There are even 3 GIT-Players to watch the code examples execute live in your browser! Great, isn't it? ;-)

Answer (score -2):

For now, I could get (almost!) all problems go away with adding a threading.Lock() - so obviously (most of) the problems were caused by concurrent threads of the same worker process trying to access a DB which is not made for that - sqlite3.

The successful solution looks like this now:

```
from django.db import transaction, IntegrityError, OperationalError

import threading
lock = threading.Lock()

def foobar():
    with lock:  
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                obj = readFromDB() 
                if foo(obj): 
                    obj.save()                                          
        except (IntegrityError, OperationalError) as e:
            print "ALERT!", e
            return ABORTED
    return CORRECTO
```

That almost always returns CORRECTO, even when hammering the server with dozens of concurrent requests, causing hundreds of DB accesses per seconds.

However, very seldom I still see a "OperationalError: database is locked". So these remaining cases are now definitely caused by process (not thread) concurrency issues. **Where is my Django DB lock, that I wish for so much?** :-)

Thanks a lot to everyone who is trying to help me!

---

I solved it. See "EDIT 4" in my original question: [Lock Django DB on 10 concurrent uwsgi workers - how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28030536/3693375)